# Working with multiple windows while using opera driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, operadriver

I am using **opera driver with opera version 12.11**.The code I use for starting the opera is :

```
if(UrlGenerator.BROWSER_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase("opera")){
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                capabilities.setCapability("opera.log.level", "CONFIG");
                capabilities.setCapability("opera.port", -1);
                capabilities.setCapability("opera.profile", ""); 
                driver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);
            }
```

It opens the the opera browser and my test runs fine.But **when I open a new window** by clicking some link or by using some other way **It opens the window in same page so switching to window fails**.
Can somebody suggests me some workaround for this?

Comment: May be the link is supposed to open in the same page? Does it behave differently when performing the same steps manually?

Comment: Yup..When I perform the same step manually it opens the page in new window.